# can proxy server set cookie?

Tags: cookies, proxy

can the proxy server intercept my https request and set cookies before actually sending the request?

I'm going a GET on an url from chrome browser. In the development tools, under "Network", I noticed that the first request, the one that I made, has cookies set. but I did not set any cookies.

any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

No it can't. To proxy HTTPS requests your browser issues HTTP CONNECT command (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/CONNECT). Proxy then creates a tunnel between the browser and a target server.

A conventional proxy can neither view nor manipulate a TLS-encrypted data stream, so a CONNECT request simply asks the proxy to open a pipe between the client and server. The proxy here is just a facilitator - it blindly forwards data in both directions without knowing anything about the contents. The negotiation of the TLS connection happens over this pipe, and the subsequent flow of requests and responses are completely opaque to the proxy.

It cannot modify or see what is being transferred as it is protected by TLS encryption.

The only way to modify HTTPS conenctions on the fly is if you install some external CA certificates on your computer. This is known as MITM Attack.